# Start Tomcat 7 Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

When I try to start tomcat7, I have this problem :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:374)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet.<clinit>(AxisAdminServlet.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1146)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm making a web service with axis2. I wouldn't work after this problem.
How can I fix this?

Comment: it is helpful along with the stacktrace to post the offending code, to the best of your ability

Comment: I make a project with axis2 and I just want to do like this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgY0pLadraE&t=35s but when I run the application I had this error                                                                            javax.servlet.ServletException: "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet AxisServlet a généré une exception
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)